# How to combine a state and an adjustment with window.setSoftInputMode()

Tags: android

I need to display the keyboard when my DialogFragment appear, so I did this :

```
dialog.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)
```

It works just fine, but I have an EditText squeezing if the keyboard is to high on screen (like when you try to use the search bar on the emoji panel).
So I put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the manifest file, but it was ignored. So I get rid of the `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE`. Then the squeezing part was fixed, but my keyboard doesn't show up automaticaly, except if I tap on the EditText.

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility#Respond) says that you can combine a state and adjustment options on  [windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode) like this :

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible| adjustPan" ... >
    ...
</activity>
```

But since it's a DialogFragment I don't need to display keyboard on the Activity, only when DialogFragment shows up.

How do I combine `stateAlwaysVisible` and `adjustPan` programmaticaly ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you can use a bitwise OR operator. So it would look like this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

... or if you use Kotlin:

```
window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

Read more about the bitwise operators here: [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#operations)